What are the details of raw Mod/CreationTime in *latex metadata and of the TZ variable?
When compiling a latex document without compression
(\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}) or when applying
pdfinfo -rawdates xxx.pdf to the PDF file,
we obtain the raw date
which is for me something like
D:20240612122515+02'00'

In contrast when I use pdfinfo -isodates xxx.pdf
then I obtain something like
2024-06-12T12:25:15+02

Essentially, the second form is more readable
by separating date from time by T and inserting - in date and inserting : in time.
Still two differences remain:

has the leading D: some significance?
In other words, can there be something different?
what is the meaning of the trailing '00' and again,
what else could there be?

Essentially what I am missing is a specification of ISO8601 and accordingly of rawdates.
Norms are expensive.
The raw dates indicate that the iso dates may have more components that in my examples.
Conversely, I am interested in the variable TZ.
Some specification I found in https://help.hcltechsw.com/onedb/2.0.1/sqr/ids_sqr_509.html but does not really fit.
Better https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html.
Is it specific for the operating system?
I know, neither Linux nor Windows are completely posix.
What I found is, that to reproduce my offset +02
I must specify TZ=UTC-02, so switch the sign.
Still no hint about the '00'.
Can anyone give a hint?
Maybe I shall tell what I need all this for:
I want to fake metadata.
The question is how to invoke *latex
to obtain a given timestamp in metadata.
It must be something like
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=$epoch_timestamp FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 TZ=???? lualatex

and the ??? must still be determined precisely.
I think could be something
like TZ=UTC-xx but more general.

the date format is described in 7.9.4 Dates in the pdf 2.0 reference that you can acquire at no costs through the pdf association https://pdfa.org/sponsored-standards/

@UlrikeFischer WOW! i did not know that the term raw date ist defined in pdf. and I did not expect the spec to be free, and finally, where to search..
On the other hand, very valuable description, Easily implemented.
Thank you a lot!

This would be worth an answer also.

The  date-time syntax D: is mandated by the PDF specification of the relevant field. The '00 are minutes so will be '30 in areas with a half hour time zone shift (eg Newfoundland UTC−02:30)
The date format is described in 7.9.4 Dates in the pdf 2.0 reference that you can acquire at no cost through the pdf association

This is the whole truth? So what I see by example is almost all what can happen in reality.
So to fake, or lets say reach predefined creation time, I just need TZ=UTC+xx:yy,
where + may also be - and :yy is optional, i.e. TZ=UTC[-+]\d\d(:\d\d)? in terms of regular expression?

@user2609605 yes well the date format  is (D:YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH'mm)  so you can reach all values using the form you showed.

@user2609605 that is, you can reach all values in the value space, but if you try to produce a PDF with some redundant zero enries omitted I don't think you can eg the trailing '00 is optional according to  pdf but I think pdftex will always add it to the creation time so you can't duplicate an existing pdf made elsewhere that does not have it

By the way, seems also a variant: '00' besides the newer '00.
Thank you a lot. Together with Ulrikes hint, I can help myself now.

you could add the info about the section in the pdf spec to the answer.

@UlrikeFischer done

good, then I don't have to write another answer and steal your tick.
